# Python change name of panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This should be super obvious, but I could not find an answer online:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = df
del df
```

How to rename `df` to `df2` without creating a copy and deleting the original?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've done what you want already.

This line

```
df2 = df
```

makes a *copy of the reference* to `df` so both variables point at the same dataframe. It does not copy the dataframe. To verify this:

```
>>> df2 is df
True
```

After that, `del df` does not delete the dataframe, it deletes the variable that is pointing to it.

Comment: still no way to rename the variable?

Comment: will do but you answered to quickly ;)

Comment: You can't rename a Python variable. There is no reason to do that. You simply create a new variable that points to the same dataframe and delete the old one (or wait for it to go out of scope, which is the same thing). If you could rename a variable that would suddenly make other code in the same module, that knows about the old name, invalid.

Comment: I see. Coming from `Matlab`, I am used to think about workspace variables a lot and like to keep this space "clean"

Comment: so what is the difference with a copy?

Comment: @user140259 Having 2 names that refer to the same object is not the same as having 2 names that refer to distinct objects. With 2 distinct objects, even if one starts out as an identical copy of the other, that situation can change. With only one object it doesn’t matter which name you use to change that object: the other name will reflect the change.